# Android - PagingDataAdapter collapse/expand

Tags: android, android-room, android-adapter, android-paging-3

I'm facing a problem in my app, this is requirement:

- Display a long list, load from large database. Data in each item is combined from many tables, many queries.

  → So, I think I can use Paging 3, to increase performance and observe for data change.
- The displayed list need to be hierarchical with parent item and children list, it can collapse, expand.

  → If I using Paging 3, how to custom PagingDataList for support collapse, expand?

**Different way:**

I use this library [FlexibleAdapter](https://github.com/davideas/FlexibleAdapter/), it support collapse/expand and sticky header adapter but I need load all data from database, it very large and low performance.

Please suggest me some solutions.

Thank in advance.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: I faced with implementing same behavior and I also use Google Paging 3. Seems like there is no simple ways to group items with this lib due to lack of ability to get current snapshot of all data (and transform it) using offered api. On each layer you can get only current page, attempts of groupping here cause issues like duplicated groups with data from different pages.
I think it can be possible if you try to implement your own adapter instead of PagingDataAdapter, but for me it's sound like overkill solution.